# TopAppBar does not drop shadow

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose

I have a TopAppBar within my Scaffold in my composable, but it is not droping a shadow as it is supposed to do:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(navController: NavController) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.appName)) },
            )
        }
    ) {
        Text("Composable content")
    }
}
```

Even if I manually set an elevation it does not drop any shadow:

```
    TopAppBar(
        title = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.appName)) },
        elevation = 4.dp
    )
```

What needs to be done so the AppBar drops a shadow?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this in Box ?

[image]

```
Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = Color.White,
    ) {
        Column (){
            Box(modifier = Modifier.height(80.dp)) {
                TopAppBar(
                    backgroundColor = Color.White,
                    title = { Text("Title") },
                    elevation = 10.dp
                )
            }
            Text(text = "Composable content", style = TextStyle(
                color = Color.Black
            ))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, while trying your code I have realized that the problem is in the `backgroundColor` property. If I set it to white as your example, the bar drops a shadow, but if I remove it or set it with `backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary` then there is no shadow...

Comment: Actually, seeing shadow in dark colors is difficult, for example try with yellow.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for the shadow)

If we look in the layout inspector we can see that topbar will be below content in the hierarchy. And no matter what elevation you will use no shadow will appear. At least in compose 1.1.1.

So to see the shadow move TopAppBar from Scaffold parameter to bottom of your content composable

```
Scaffold() {
Box(){
... some content
TopAppBar()
}
}
```